# If $f$ has non-tangential finite limit in $1$, then $\lim_{r \to 1^-} (1 - r) f'(r) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$, such that $f$ has non-tangential finite limit in $1$. How can I show that $\lim_{{r \to 1} \atop {r \in (0 , 1)}} (1 - r) f'(r) = 0$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Cauchy's Estimates, in the disk $D(r, (1-r)/2)$.